# Publish App to Google Play from Android Studio Beta build?

Tags: android, android-studio

Can someone please tell me if switching to Beta version of Android Studio, it doesn't make problems in future to publish app or app updates on Google Play?

Comment: It does not....

Comment: Beta software (as well as production software) can always have some error.  However, as soon as they are detected, they are fixed. Moreover in a software of this relevance. So if the fear to face an error makes you doubt whether to use a software, you might want to go back to a typerwriter.

Answer (score 1):

App updates are related to your code, not the IDE. If you really wanted to, you could even write out the entire app in Notepad/Vim and compile via CLI.

The only difference between Android Studio GA and Beta versions is that Beta versions have tendencially got more bugs and issues. Nothing that should hinder publishing an app to App stores in any way.

Personally, if you are newby, I would stick with Release versions, keep them updated (your dependencies as well) but either way you should be OK.

Hope it helps.

Comment: the problem is that i had 2 years ago same problem, i build release apk with preview version of studio and gradle build tools, and Google play refused to accept the versions builded from preview, only accepted compiled from release version

Comment: this is a (surprisingly) very valid answer to a very vague and broad question :) but this is true, the IDE has nothing to do with this - a build server is proof of this

Comment: @NIchiforTcaci with the information you've provided we can't help you, we also don't answer questions related to store policies here, [because we are not the store](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-cant-i-ask-customer-service-related-questions/255746#255746)